# SQL to select a single random row with a where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, random, row

I am trying to get a single random row from all the rows that satisfy the where clause in the SQL. I am using the following SQL but getting the corresponding error.

```
SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE (long='0' AND lat='0') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Error:
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long='0' AND lat='0') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: Long is a keyword in SQL. You can't use it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LONG is Reserved Words

```
SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE (`long`='0' AND lat='0') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT *
  FROM (  SELECT *
            FROM xyz
           WHERE (`long`='0' AND lat='0')
        ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) LIMIT 1
```